# Amcharts with bootstrap 3.3.1 modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, amcharts

When I insert amchart into bootstrap 3.3.1 modal, the data is not showing, but outside of the modal it's showing. The code is following:

html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Large modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
      <div id="chartdiv" style="width:100%; height:600px;"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
AmCharts.ready(function () {
    generateChartData();
    createStockChart();
});

var chartData1 = [];
var chartData2 = [];
var chartData3 = [];
var chartData4 = [];

function generateChartData() {
    var firstDate = new Date();
    firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 500);
    firstDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);

        var a1 = Math.round(Math.random() * (40 + i)) + 100 + i;
        var b1 = Math.round(Math.random() * (1000 + i)) + 500 + i * 2;

        var a2 = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 + i)) + 200 + i;
        var b2 = Math.round(Math.random() * (1000 + i)) + 600 + i * 2;

        var a3 = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 + i)) + 200;
        var b3 = Math.round(Math.random() * (1000 + i)) + 600 + i * 2;

        var a4 = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 + i)) + 200 + i;
        var b4 = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 + i)) + 600 + i;

        chartData1.push({
            date: newDate,
            value: a1,
            volume: b1
        });
        chartData2.push({
            date: newDate,
            value: a2,
            volume: b2
        });
        chartData3.push({
            date: newDate,
            value: a3,
            volume: b3
        });
        chartData4.push({
            date: newDate,
            value: a4,
            volume: b4
        });
    }
}

function createStockChart() {
    var chart = new AmCharts.AmStockChart();
    chart.pathToImages = "/static/images/";

    // DATASETS //////////////////////////////////////////
    // create data sets first
    var dataSet1 = new AmCharts.DataSet();
    dataSet1.title = "first data set";
    dataSet1.fieldMappings = [
        {
            fromField: "value",
            toField: "value"
        },
        {
            fromField: "volume",
            toField: "volume"
        }
    ];
    dataSet1.dataProvider = chartData1;
    dataSet1.categoryField = "date";

    var dataSet2 = new AmCharts.DataSet();
    dataSet2.title = "second data set";
    dataSet2.fieldMappings = [
        {
            fromField: "value",
            toField: "value"
        },
        {
            fromField: "volume",
            toField: "volume"
       }
    ];
    dataSet2.dataProvider = chartData2;
    dataSet2.categoryField = "date";

    var dataSet3 = new AmCharts.DataSet();
    dataSet3.title = "third data set";
    dataSet3.fieldMappings = [
        {
            fromField: "value",
            toField: "value"
        },
        {
            fromField: "volume",
            toField: "volume"
        }
    ];
    dataSet3.dataProvider = chartData3;
    dataSet3.categoryField = "date";

    var dataSet4 = new AmCharts.DataSet();
    dataSet4.title = "fourth data set";
    dataSet4.fieldMappings = [
        {
            fromField: "value",
            toField: "value"
        },
        {
            fromField: "volume",
            toField: "volume"
        }
    ];
    dataSet4.dataProvider = chartData4;
    dataSet4.categoryField = "date";

    // set data sets to the chart
    chart.dataSets = [dataSet1, dataSet2, dataSet3, dataSet4];

    // PANELS ///////////////////////////////////////////
    // first stock panel
    var stockPanel1 = new AmCharts.StockPanel();
    stockPanel1.showCategoryAxis = false;
    stockPanel1.title = "Value";
    stockPanel1.percentHeight = 70;

    // graph of first stock panel
    var graph1 = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
    graph1.valueField = "value";
    graph1.comparable = true;
    graph1.compareField = "value";
    graph1.bullet = "round";
    graph1.bulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
    graph1.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
    graph1.balloonText = "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>";
    graph1.compareGraphBalloonText = "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>";
    graph1.compareGraphBullet = "round";
    graph1.compareGraphBulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
    graph1.compareGraphBulletBorderAlpha = 1;
    stockPanel1.addStockGraph(graph1);

    // create stock legend
    var stockLegend1 = new AmCharts.StockLegend();
    stockLegend1.periodValueTextComparing = "[[percents.value.close]]%";
    stockLegend1.periodValueTextRegular = "[[value.close]]";
    stockPanel1.stockLegend = stockLegend1;


    // second stock panel
    var stockPanel2 = new AmCharts.StockPanel();
    stockPanel2.title = "Volume";
    stockPanel2.percentHeight = 30;
    var graph2 = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
    graph2.valueField = "volume";
    graph2.type = "column";
    graph2.showBalloon = false;
    graph2.fillAlphas = 1;
    stockPanel2.addStockGraph(graph2);

    var stockLegend2 = new AmCharts.StockLegend();
    stockLegend2.periodValueTextRegular = "[[value.close]]";
    stockPanel2.stockLegend = stockLegend2;

    // set panels to the chart
    chart.panels = [stockPanel1, stockPanel2];


    // OTHER SETTINGS ////////////////////////////////////
    var sbsettings = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbarSettings();
    sbsettings.graph = graph1;
    chart.chartScrollbarSettings = sbsettings;

    // CURSOR
    var cursorSettings = new AmCharts.ChartCursorSettings();
    cursorSettings.valueBalloonsEnabled = true;
    chart.chartCursorSettings = cursorSettings;


    // PERIOD SELECTOR ///////////////////////////////////
    var periodSelector = new AmCharts.PeriodSelector();
    periodSelector.position = "left";
    periodSelector.periods = [
        {
            period: "DD",
            count: 10,
            label: "10 days"
        },
        {
            period: "MM",
            selected: true,
            count: 1,
            label: "1 month"
        },
        {
            period: "YYYY",
            count: 1,
            label: "1 year"
        },
        {
            period: "YTD",
            label: "YTD"
        },
        {
            period: "MAX",
            label: "MAX"
        }
    ];
    chart.periodSelector = periodSelector;


    // DATA SET SELECTOR
    var dataSetSelector = new AmCharts.DataSetSelector();
    dataSetSelector.position = "left";
    chart.dataSetSelector = dataSetSelector;

    chart.write('chartdiv');
}
```

And the html will only show part of the stock figure, is it the problem that when modal insert svg part? Is there any conflicts between bootstrap and amcharts?

The figure is like: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that chart can't calculate it's own size in hidden containers. The fix is to make it recalculate the size **after** modal is displayed.

To do so you can tap into Bootstrap's modal event "shown.bs.modal". I.e.:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  chart.invalidateSize();
})
```

Replace "chart" with your own global variable you have stored your chart into. (if different)